# Can you use BCS External Content Types in conjunction with Product Catalogs in 2013?

Tags: 2013, bcs, cross-site-publishing

Does anybody know if it is possible to use an External Content Type as the basis for a Product Catalog in SharePoint 2013? So if we store a load of Product data in a database are we then able to surface this in a SharePoint Product catalog via BCS and then use Content By Search / Cross Site Publishing to push this content on to web pages?

I'm thinking this probably isn't possible - if not what's the best approach to achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: More info can be found here: http://sivarajan.me/post/SharePoint-2013-Develop-a-Publishing-portal-using-BCS-Enterprise-Search-Cross-site-publishing-and-Content-Search-Web-Part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a catalog connection in SharePoint 2013, the following items get configured for you automatically:

- Result Source
- Managed Navigation
- Catalog Category Page
- Catalog Item Page

When using BCS External Content Types, you have to configure all of the items above manually but it is definitely possible. These are some high-level steps:

- Create the external content types, make sure to set a Title field and default action url
- Crawl external content, create new managed properties as needed
- Create result sources by building search queries that only returns items for specific external content types
- Create catalog category and item pages, add and configure search web parts
- Link your catalog pages to site navigation

The following blog post should get you started: [Business Connectivity Services, External Content Types and Content By Search in SharePoint 2013 – Part 1](http://www.blendmaster.net/blog/2013/02/business-connectivity-services-external-content-type-and-content-by-search-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1/). The next blog post will show how to consume the external content on the publishing site using search web parts.

Comment: Vassili, thanks for your quick response, I'll definitely be giving your very timely post a read through. Thanks.

Comment: @j.strugnell just published the second part of the blog post: http://www.blendmaster.net/blog/2013/02/business-connectivity-services-external-content-types-and-content-by-search-in-sharepoint-2013-part-2/